# MinGW, linking to a dll on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, dll, mingw

I'm trying to use a library I received from a camera vendor in a sample program. I have a .dll and a .lib file for the library. My compile command is:

```
g++  -o "Win32App.exe" -L"..\..\SK develop\SK91GigE-WIN\Lib" obj/winmain.o obj/callbacks.o obj/resource.o -s -lcomctl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lSK91GigE_x64
```

and I get:

```
obj/winmain.o:winmain.cpp:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to `SK_LOADDLL'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

having a look on the .lib with nm shows:

```
BFD: SK91GigE_x64.lib(SK91GigE_x64.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive 
nm: SK91GigE_x64.dll: File format not recognized
```

and for the dll it outputs:

```
nm: SK91GigE_x64.dll: File format not recognized
```

Any ideas how I can modify that lib to include it?

Comment: You are using 64 bit mingw right?

Answer (score 5):

windows path variable pointed to 32 bit MinGW. setting the path to the 64bit version of MinGW solved the problem. I didn't check that